# Platformer game set Tiles

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on a side scroller runner game. The idea is to kill enemies while jumping from platforms, the speed is fixed and the platforms are generated randomly at positions. The issue I have is, my platforms are generated randomly in terms of width, sometimes its big and sometimes small, in terms of width.

My question is, how would I manually place the textures differently at the start of the platform and one at the end, keeping in mind that I create my platforms by duplicating a single cube. Can this be done using a forloop?

EDIT

This is how the platforms are created, using a forloop and putting one next the other. Basically I need to somehow find the first and the last cube and put different texture on it, or most likely instantiate a different cube.

```
    objectQueue = new Queue<Transform>(numberOfObjects);
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++)
    {
        objectQueue.Enqueue((Transform)Instantiate(prefab));
    }
    nextPosition = startPosition;
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++)
    {
        Recycle();
    }
```

Comment: you'll have to provide some code

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I get it right how you do this, a simple if-statement inside the for-loop should do, shouldn't it?

```
if(i == 0)
{
    // cube with start texture
}
else if(i == numberOfObjects - 1)
{
    // cube with end texture
}
else
{
    // cube with middle texture
}
```